# macular insult during optic neuritis

Tags: physiology, ophthalmology, inflammation

In our lecture today, the professor gave us a trick question: although papilledema and most optic nerve/disc pathology cause either generalized visual field depression or visual field defects, sparing the macular area (in early stages), optic neuritis causes central scotoma first. I think it's due to the fact that macula has extensive dual blood supply, and most causes of optical neuritis are blood-borne :

1. bacterial: lyme disease,etc.
2. viral: mumps
3. autoimmune: bech's, multiple sclerosis,etc.

this is further reinforced by the fact that toxic optical neuritis presents with either central or co-central scotoma, and the macular sparing occurs in central retinal artery occlusion patients with [patent Cilioretinal blood supply](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7010472/). Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Optic neuropathy *vs* optic neuritis

Stat Pearls (Guier and Stokkermans 2021. [NBK557853](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK557853/)) notes that:

> A wide range of conditions including infections, trauma, vascular insufficiency, metastases, toxins, or nutritional deficiencies may cause **optic neuropathies**.

However, **optic neuritis** (ON) is:

> An inflammatory condition that demyelinates the optic nerve and degrades vision in one or both eyes.

##### Visual field defects seen in optic neuritis

A study by Nevalainen and colleagues (2008. PMID [18239928](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18239928/)) of 99 patients with ON found that:

> Central scotomas were the most common finding in associated eyes, covering 41% of all [visual field defects (VFD)] in affected eyes. Nerve fibre bundle defects were found in 29% and paracentral scotomas in 14% of all VFDs.

Thus, while central scotoma is the most common visual field defect in ON, it is not the only possible finding.

##### Pathophysiology of visual field defects in optic neuritis

Guier and Stokkermans note that:

> The mechanism responsible for acute optic neuritis (ON) has not been definitively identified but it is believed that an autoimmune reaction damages the myelin sheath that encompasses neurons within the optic nerve.

Fang and colleagues (1999. PMID [10577522](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10577522/)) have presented two competing hypotheses which seem to continue to this day.

> It is possible that optic neuritis has a predilection for certain axon bundles. For example, a predilection for the maculopapillary bundle could have explained the central scotomas observed by Nikoskelainen and Reikkinen. However, it is also possible that optic neuritis damages the optic nerve in a more random manner. In this model, visual field damage in optic neuritis could occur throughout the field, and the depth of the field defect in any particular area would be related to the amount of damage to axons subserving that area.

##### Conclusion

The most convincing hypothesis for why central scotoma is a feature of optic neuritis is because the inflammatory process has a predilection to the specific axons which connect the central retina to the brain. However, the exact mechanism remains elusive.

Comment: wouldn't my approach be considered a valid hypothesis to be tested ? i mean the mechanism is not known but autoimmune and self-reacting immune cells would be in the blood stream so more blood supply = more access to inflammatory mediators and cells.